# how to reuse a zenity dialog?

Tags: bash, zenity

Is possible to reuse a zenity dialog? A list for example.
Assign it to a variable it gets the value of the selected item. So when use the variable I just get the selected item' s value.

Comment: I've managed what I wanted. I don't know if is possible what I'm asking(probably not), but I used a method in a while loop and I achive what I wanted.

Comment: You need to be a bit more particular in what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are asking for? Your request is bit unclear. See this test with yad (advanced fork of zenity). Same test will work with zenity as well:

```
$ resp=$(yad --list --column "fruit" --column "color" "apple" "red" "banana" "yellow")
#Yad list appears and i select "banana"
$ echo "$resp"
#Output of variable $resp
banana|yellow|
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mean the output. I just want to display again the list to choose another item without the need to rewrite the same list dialog multiple times. Anyway as I wrote I found a solution by using a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of zenity which saves the input of zenity to $a varible and calls that in a command to rename sudo to X input:

```
a=$(zenity --entry --title="Rename Sudo") && cd /usr/bin/ && $(sudo mv sudo $a)
```

type 
**zenity --version** 
and then visit [Zenity Manual](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/)
from the **man zenity** pages type this if you want more advanced gtk ([GIMP TOOL KIT](https://www.gtk.org/)) options:

**zenity --help-gtk**

Are you trying to set a string and run it like:

```
 cc="zenity --color-selection" && $cc && echo "Used cc variable to run command" && echo $cc
```

**You can omit the last two echo commands** but I added them to show you how it worked. If you plan on saving output of zenity try something like:

**cc="zenity --color-selection" && color=$($cc) && echo "Used cc variable to run command" && echo $cc && echo "Your color was: " $color**

Comment: The $(foobar) tries to execute foobar